# Use arrow cursor for textbox

Tags: ms-access, forms, textbox, cursor, ms-access-2003

I am using a textbox in lieu of a button in a MS Access 2003 form. When I hover over the textbox, the cursor changes to an insertion point. Is there any way to keep the cursor a mouse (and keep the textbox clickable- so the "enabled" property can't be set to "no")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mouse move event of the textbox, set:

```
screen.MousePointer = 1
```

Comment: After setting this property in Access 2013 and hovering over the textbox, I get a message: `Microsoft Access cannot find the object 'screen.'`

Answer (score 0):

This will also be useful, you can use it as reference and build upon it to fit your needs.

Paste into module:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' Declarations for setting the cursor icon when called
Public Const IDC_HAND = 32649&
Public Const IDC_ARROW = 32512&
Public Declare Function LoadCursor Lib "user32" Alias "LoadCursorA" (ByVal hInstance As Long, ByVal lpCursorName As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SetCursor Lib "user32" (ByVal hCursor As Long) As Long
```

How to call the hyperlink hand (remember to use the proper module name):

```
CursorModule.SetCursor LoadCursor(0, IDC_HAND)
```

How to call the default cursor shape:

```
CursorModule.SetCursor LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW)
```

Source:
[Changing Cursor Shape](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=188859)